# Best practice for scripting Azure resource creation

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm creating a test environment in Azure.  I want to have an accurate script of what of the configuration so it's easy to replicate for other test, pre-prod and prod environments later on.  The environment has an existing subscription, and I want the entire hierarchy of resources from Resource Groups through to Web Apps to be created by script.

I'm currently rolling my own script in PowerShell utilising [AzureRm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125356.aspx).  This is working well, but I can't help feel I'm reinventing the wheel.  What is the existing method for creating an entire Azure environment by script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that way is called Azure Resource Manager Templates. Quote:

With Resource Manager, you can create a template (in JSON format) that defines the infrastructure and configuration of your Azure solution. By using a template, you can repeatedly deploy your solution throughout its lifecycle and have confidence your resources are deployed in a consistent state. When you create a solution from the portal, the solution automatically includes a deployment template. You do not have to create your template from scratch because you can start with the template for your solution and customize it to meet your specific needs. You can retrieve a template for an existing resource group by either exporting the current state of the resource group, or viewing the template used for a particular deployment. Viewing the exported template is a helpful way to learn about the template syntax.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview#template-deployment

Edit: you can use powershell, azure cli, azure cli2, azure sdk to deploy those templates (or simply Azure portal, search for "Template Deployment")